# Passing checked value of checkbox in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I had a modal form where you are adding a user and after saving it, it would pass the data to the table. I was able to pass the name form. I want to pass the value of the checkbox in the form to the table if it is checked or not.

Modal Form

```
<div id="addUser" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div>
                <label>Full Name</label>
                <div>
                    <input class="form-control" id="fullname" type="text" required/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div >
                <label>Permissions</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="add" value="Add" data-parsley-multiple="status">
                    <label>Add</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="edit" value="Edit" data-parsley-multiple="status">
                    <label>Edit</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="delete" value="Delete" data-parsley-multiple="status">
                    <label>Delete</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <button class="btn" id="saveUser">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#saveUser").click(function () {
    t.row.add(['', 
        '<input class="form-control" type="text" name="fullname[]" value="'+$("#fullname").val()+'" readonly>',
        '<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="'+$("#add").val()+'" data-parsley-multiple="status">',
        '<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="'+$("#edit").val()+'" data-parsley-multiple="status">',
        '<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="'+$("#delete").val()+'" data-parsley-multiple="status">',
    ]).draw(false); 
});
```

As you notice in my JS code, I am using datatable codes to add a row. I was able to pass the fullname and also the value of the checkbox (e.g. add, delete). However, I want to pass the check value. If it is check/uncheck in the modal, the checked/unchecked value will pass.

Comment: basically, `if ($("#add").is(':checked')) { /* IS CHECKED */ } else { /* IS NOT CHECKED */ }`

Comment: You always know the value (add/edit/delete) - you need to set the `checked` attribute.  Note that 'checked' is a flag, you can't have `checked='false'`  So something like `"... value='add' " + ($("#add").is(":checked") ? "checked" : "") + " data-..."`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `checked` HTML property, and set its value with the corresponding `checkbox` checked value.

***UPDATE***

As @freedomn-m mentioned, the `checked="false"` will make the the `checkbox` checked, So you need conditionally set the attribute without a value.

For example

```
'<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="permissions[]"  ' +  $("#add")[0].checked ? 'checked': '' +' data-parsley-multiple="status">'
```

```js
        $("#saveUser").click(function () {
            t.row
                .add([
                    "",
                    `<input class="form-control" type="text" name="fullname[]" value="${$(
                        "#fullname"
                    ).val()}" readonly>`,
                    `<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" ${
                        $("#add")[0].checked ? "checked" : ""
                    } data-parsley-multiple="status">`,
                    `<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" ${
                        $("#edit")[0].checked ? "checked" : ""
                    } data-parsley-multiple="status">`,
                    `<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" ${
                        $("#delete")[0].checked ? "checked" : ""
                    } data-parsley-multiple="status">`,
                ])
                .draw(false);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="addUser" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div>
                <label>Full Name</label>
                <div>
                    <input class="form-control" id="fullname" type="text" required/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div >
                <label>Permissions</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="add" value="Add" data-parsley-multiple="status">
                    <label>Add</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="edit" value="Edit" data-parsley-multiple="status">
                    <label>Edit</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="delete" value="Delete" data-parsley-multiple="status">
                    <label>Delete</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <button class="btn" id="saveUser">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have a syntax error when concatenating the checked status in the string

Comment: Note: `checked` is a flag attribute, it doesn't have/use a value, ie, `checked='false'` is the same as `checked`

Comment: Yes, thanks for notifying, I just update it.

Comment: Please *run your snippet* before saving - there's now a different error (or don't use a snippet as it's just OPs code copied).

Comment: The snippet shouldn't work as `t` isn't defined in the question code.

Comment: Without the snippet working, you can't see that `checked='false'` is created a checked checkbox.

Comment: Yes, I just update the answer with your note, Thanks.

Comment: I had an error. Instead showing a checkbox, it is the word "checked" is shown.

Comment: It should be ```($("#add").is(":checked") ? "checked" : "") + "``` instead of ```$("#add")[0].checked ? 'checked': ''``` as @freedomn-m commented above

Comment: When using `?:` in js string concatenation, it *must* surrounded by `()` otherwise js gets confused as to which bit is being concatenated.   is:checked vs [0].checked are essentially the same.  This answer just needs:  `+  $("#add")[0].checked ? 'checked': '' +` changed to `+ ($("#add")[0].checked ? 'checked': '') +` (or use string interpolation (template literals))

Comment: thanks. maybe @Mina should edit his answer to this one so that I can mark it as the best one

Comment: I Updated the answer with `template literals`, as string concatenation is really confusing.